# Как вы делаете WinForms интерфейсы?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net, visual-studio

Привет, Хэшкод!

Хочу поинтересоваться у людей, делающих интерфейсы на WinForms, как обстоят их дела и легко ли им живётся.

В чём собственно проблема. У разработчика интерфейса на WinForms есть три пути:

1. Довольствоваться стандартными контролами.
2. Писать свои.
3. Скачивать/покупать сторонние.

Первый варинт, отпадает сразу, как только начинаешь вглядываться в стандартные контролы, предоставляемые visual studio. Нет, лично я ничего не имею против хорошо причёсанных минималистичных приложений, использующих только лишь родные кнопочки, комбобоксы и пр., но по личному опыту, с каждым годом после выхода 2007-го офиса, юзеры всё больше и больше воротят нос от 'скучных' компонентов.

На написание собственных контролов я готов пойти в случае долговременного проекта, когда дело действительно того стоит. В остальных же случаях хотелось бы готовых решений.

На сторонние компоненты возлагалось больше всего надежд, но как я понял они либо платные либо слеплены на скорою руку в вырви-глаз стиле. Может я что-то пропустил, и в свободном доступе есть масса хороших коллекций контролов? Ведь популярная технология, должны быть решения.

*В качестве ответа на вопрос меня вполне устроит либо ссылка на бесплатную коллекцию контролов, либо фраза «WinForms метрв».*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Как оказалось, на [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/) имеется весьма неплохая коллекция бесплатных контролов. Они, конечно, уступают платным решениям, но при усердном поиске и правильном использовании начинают выглядеть весьма прилично, и что самое главное сочетаться друг с другом.

**Собственно [сама коллекция.](http://www.codeproject.com/Chapters/1/Desktop-Development.aspx)**

Comment: Поправьте, пожалуйста, ссылку, интересно. Ваша ведёт на "The top 50 Articles on Desktop Development".

Answer (score 12):

Согласно моему ИМХО, я бы рекомендовал плавно переходить на WPF. Стандартные возможности по интеграции WPF и WinForms в одном приложении позволяют это делать буквально "плавно" и безболезненно.

А в чем преимущество WPF? В контексте вашего вопроса, на нем довольно легко делать нескучные компоненты. Во-первых, и приятно, что самому делать проще, во-вторых, это же приводит к тому, что сообщество активно их создает под бесплатными лицензиями, и необходимости кому-то платить или самому мучиться нет.

Answer (score 5):

Стандартные очень даже ничего, 
для создания своих необходимы крепкие знания иерархии контролов .NET.
Про другие - Сеть полна бесплатными и довольно качественными контролами, гугл да сурсфордж да кодпрожект в помощь...

Comment: Вот честно, лучшее из бесплатного, что я нашел — отдельно наборы кнопочек, отдельно чекбоксов и пр. мелочи. И что характерно, каждая такая коллекция обладат своим насыщенным стилем, что делает невозможным использование их в одной программе.

Answer (score 5):

Внешний вид и неприятные баги Visual Studio 2010 отбивают всякое желание переходить на WPF. Используем платные компоненты. MapXtreme для карт, DevExpress для всего остального.

Comment: Вы какой-то другой VS 2010 пользуетесь, чем все остальные.

Comment: С тем, что VS2008 работала лучше, согласны все наши сотрудники. Единственное, чем лучше VS2010 - она не падает при компиляции кода с большой вложенностью операторов в одном методе на C++.